# Notifying all the waiting threads in case the instance is created in case of singleton double lock check

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

```
public static Singleton getInstance()
{ 
if (instance == null)
    {
    synchronized(Singleton.class) {  //1
    if (instance == null)          //2
    instance = new Singleton();  //3
        }
    }
    return instance; //4
}
```

In the code above, suppose ten threads are calling this method, all of them crossed the first if condition, then one thread enters into the synchronized block and creates the instances. Remaining 9 thread should come one by one even if the instance is created they need to go through the synchronized block, As soon as any of the threads creates the Singleton instance all the other threads should not wait. Tell me if there is some solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no conditional synchronized. Meaning that whenever you are using synchronized, it is enforced the whole time.
In the example above it would of course be an option to initialize the Singleton in a static block, then you do not need the synchronized block for the getter.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want all the nine other threads to run through without acquiring the lock one at a time.

Firstly I feel compelled to mention that the performance issue from acquiring the lock after waiting for initialisation is tiny. Secondly, singletons are evil and there are better ways to implement them.

However, if you want to partially re-implement locks then you can do this. There may be some ready-made `Future` for doing this, but I can't see anything. Anyway, bad implementation off the top of my head:

```
private static final AtomicReference<Object> ref = new AtomicReference<>();
    // <Object> as we require two distinguished values. :(
    // (I guess could use a mark.)

public static Singleton getInstance() {
    for (;;) { // May want to play with park to avoid spinning.
        Object obj = ref.get();
        if (obj instanceof Singleton) {
           return (Singleton)obj;
        }
        if (ref.weakCompareAndSet(null, Thread.currentThread())) {
            Singleton instance = null; // To reset on fail.
            try {
                instance = new Singleton();
            } finally {
                ref.set(instance);
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

I guess we can do slightly better without getting too complicated, again assuming no exceptions:

```
    {
        Object obj = ref.get();
        if (obj instanceof Singleton) {
           return (Singleton)obj;
        }
    }

    if (ref.compareAndSet(null, Thread.currentThread())) {
        Singleton instance = new Singleton();
        ref.set(instance);
        return instance;
    }

    for (;;) {
        Object obj = ref.get();
        if (obj instanceof Singleton) {
           return (Singleton)obj;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I see why are you calling my approach "naive"... :)

Answer (score 0):

As your design stands the remaining threads will indeed have to go through one thread at a a time - and really for any locking strategy like this you'll have the same outcome. That said, the cost of the locking is insignificant nowadays.

Note that although not shown, the `instance` variable has to be `volatile` for this idiom to work.

If you want a pattern that does what you're after (lazy initialization with low cost) then I'd recommend the static initialization method instead (as recommended by Brian Goetz):

```
public class Singleton {
    static class Holder {
        static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }

    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }
```

This approach is consice and tidy, and is threadsafe too, and in your case the first thread to access the static `getInstance` method (or any static method really) will pay the cost of initialization, but all subsequent ones wont, and wont block either.

Answer (score -1):

I think its good code and the blocking time will not be that much considering that Singleton is not very complex structured class or does not have too many thing to load in initialization in the constructor. If all thread comes to the same time they have to wait until first object is created by any one of the thread.